# Strange JSON output from PHP json_encode()

Tags: php, json

I'm playing with JSON using PHP. I'm using `json_encode()` function to create JSON. Hovewer I've got strange JSON output:

```
[

    {
        "0": "1",
        "1": "test",
        "2": "test",
        "ID": "1",
        "title": "test",
        "imageUrl": "test"
    },
    {
        "0": "2",
        "1": "welcome",
        "2": "http://overkiller.pl/Smokopedia/Images/01.jpg",
        "ID": "2",
        "title": "welcome",
        "imageUrl": "http://overkiller.pl/Smokopedia/Images/01.jpg"
    }

]
```

Why I am getting this sort JSON how to get rid these numbers from it?
My **PHP** code:

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    $connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'sam1');
    $array = array();
    if($connection)
    {
        mysql_select_db("Smokopedia");
        $result = mysql_query("Select * from mainMenu");
        if($result)
        {
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
            {
                array_push($array, $row);
            }
            echo json_encode($array);
        }else
        {
            $errorJson = array(
                    message => 'Result is empty or incorrect',
                    type => 'error'
                );
            echo json_encode($errorJson);
        }
    }
    mysql_close();

?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`mysql_fetch_array` includes both numeric indexed keys and column name indexed keys.

Change it to `mysql_fetch_assoc` and you'll get the end result you need.

---

Note though, that the entire mysql extension is deprecated and you should consider switching to PDO or Mysqli.

Comment: Thank you. I've forgot about that function in PHP.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is you are fetching an array, which includes both numerical indexes and string keys.

Change to mysql_fetch_assoc

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_ssoc($result))
```

---

Side note: the `mysql_*` library is deprecated. Considered upgrading to a modern API such as MySQLi or PDO.